# WhenEvent not triggering

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, event-detection

I have a PDE describing a bending beam which I want to solve numerically.

```
a=1;

b=0.1;

Approx[x_, ϵ_] := Approx[x, ϵ] = ϵ/(Pi*(x^2 + ϵ^2)) 

Initial = {p[x, 0] == 0.5, q[x, 0] == 0.5};

CisTrans = 
  {Derivative[0, 1][p][x, t] == 10*(1 - p[x, t]) - p[x, t], 
   Derivative[0, 1][q][x, t] == -q[x, t]};

Deflection = 
  {Derivative[0, 2][w][x, t] + a*Derivative[0, 1][w][x, t] + 
   Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t] == -b*(p[x, t] - q[x, t]) *
   Approx[x - 1, 10^(-1000)]};

s = 
   NDSolveValue[
    {Initial, CisTrans, Deflection,  Derivative[2, 0][w][x, t] == u[x, t], 
     u[1, t] == 0, u[x, 0] == 1, w[x, 0] == 0, w[0, t] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[t == 0.5, Print[t]]}, 
    w, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

This `NDSolveValue` solves the PDE, but ignores my `WhenEvent`, so 0.5 is not printed, while in other PDE's the `WhenEvent` is not ignored. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: aside to your actual question, your system produces *vastly* different results if you adjust the limit of the time domain ( see what you get if you just solve over `t,0,1/2` ) . This tells me the default solution method is a poor choice, although I didn't have any luck doing better.

Comment: another aside I cant make any sense of what `Approx` is supposed to do. It is essentially zero everywhere and then blows up exactly on the x=1 boundary.  (off hand I think it never gets evaluated exactly at the boundary )

Comment: IIFC, you have to have explicit time integration (e.g., with the method of lines) for `WhenEvent` to work, and then it only applies to the time-stepping.  (While you may call your variable `t`, it is being treated as one of the spatial variables in `NDSolve` above.)

Comment: @george2079 `Approx` seems to be an [approximate Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Representations_of_the_delta_function).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform good call, so it is.  `NDSolve` will not integrate it properly however.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution to your problem, but a possible source of the problem.
Sometimes, when the method to obtain the `InterpolatingFunction` type solution is `Unstructured`, it seems that `WhenEvent[]` call doesn't trigger any response. This is most likely the case for complicated PDE or system of PDE's.

Couple of examples from the docs(ref/NDSolve):

One where `WhenEvent[]` doesn't work:

```
\[CapitalOmega] = 
  RegionDifference[RegionUnion[Disk[], Rectangle[{0, -1}, {2, 1}]], 
   Disk[{2, 0}]];
ufun = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 1., 
       PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], (x - 2)^2 + y^2 == 1, 
         Function[x, x - {2, 0}]], DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, 
         0 < x < 2 - 10^(-6) && (y <= -1 || y >= 1)], 
   WhenEvent[x == 0, Print[x]]}, u, 
     Element[{x, y}, \[CapitalOmega]]]
```

However, in this one it works just fine(even if the method utilised was `Unstructured`):

```
\[CapitalOmega] = 
  RegionDifference[
   RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}], 
    Rectangle[{9/10, 0}, {11/10, 4/10}]], 
   Rectangle[{9/10, 6/10}, {11/10, 1}]];
sol = First[
  NDSolve[{D[u[t, x, y], {t, 2}] - Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 0,
     DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 0, True], 
    u[0, x, y] == 2*Exp[-125 ((x - 0.25)^2 + (y - 0.5)^2)], 
    Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][0, x, y] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[t == 0.1, Print@t]}, 
   u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]]
```